# RabbitMQ: publish in node.js subscribe in Java

Tags: java, node.js, rabbitmq

Given the following publisher in `node.js` and the following subscriber in `java` (this setup is fully functional) I have the following two questions:

1. What should I use as the third argument in `queueBind` and why? Why does it works as is (`"test"` is a random pick)?
2. Is there a way to specify queue in addition to exchange in `rabbit.js`? If yes then how? If not then why and which module should I use instead (code example would be welcome)?

```js
// node.js
var context = require("rabbit.js").createContext();

var pub = context.socket('PUB');
pub.connect(config.exchange);

server.post("/message/:msg", function(req, res) {
    pub.write(req.params.msg, 'utf8');
    res.end();
});
```

```java
// java
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost(host);
try {
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.exchangeDeclare(exchange, "fanout");

    String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
    channel.queueBind(queueName, exchange, "test"); // Question1: what should I use as the third argument and why?
    // Question2: is there a way to configure rabbit.js with a queue name instead?
    //channel.queueDeclare(queueName, false, false, false, null);

    QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
    channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);

    try {
        while (true) {
            QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
            LOG.info("Received message: " + message);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOG.catching(e);
    } finally {
        channel.close();
        connection.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOG.catching(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Own answer, what I've digged up so far:

1. The third argument, the routing key, is what is known as `topic` in `rabbit.js`. By supplying `test` I am only subscribing to messages send to the `test` topic or without a topic set (default in `rabbit.js`). If I were to use topic in the publisher as well, I could use `pub.publish(topic, message, encoding)` instead of `pub.write(message, encoding)` or supply it to the `connect` method
2. Does not look so and still do not know why really. The argument goes that `rabbit.js` is a higher-level library and it, therefore, makes certain simplifications. Why exactly this simplification is made I do not know. However, I primarily wanted to use a single exchange for multiple communication threads, which I can also achieve by using topics/routing keys. So not a big deal.